# Draw in a canvas explanation

Tags: javascript, function

I want to draw in a canvas, i saw an example but i don't understand this : `x:event.clientX - rect.left,`
in this part of the code :

```
getMousePos : function(event) {
        rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return{
            x:event.clientX - rect.left,
            y:event.clientY - rect.top
        };
    },
```

What does mean the `-` ? Sorry it's a beginner question :D

Comment: I would recomand reading Jhon's Reisig's [getBoundingClientRect is Awesome](https://johnresig.com/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/)

Comment: Do you mean you're fluently reading object structures and understanding how event handlers work, but you don't know the subtraction operator ..? This has to be a troll!

Comment: VTC as won't help future readers, there is no way someone who doesn't understand the `-` sign will be able to fall on this Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

It is a subtraction, as simple as `5 - 3 = 2`

The reason of this subtraction is that the properties clientX and clientY represent the coordinates X and Y of the event *inside the whole document*.

The variable `rect` contains the position of your canvas inside the document, so `event.clientX - rect.left` gives you the horizontal position, in pixel, *relative to the canvas* in which you are trying to draw.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple subtraction sign, just a mathematical operation between two coordinates:

`event.clientX - rect.left`